# Generic Repository Pattern

Tags: generics

NWBI, Ièm having some trouble with using or implementing a Generic Repository Patter. with Linq To Entities. I'm inheriting a legacy application with object based crud operations, I would like to create a Generic Factory to Entities based on the object type being passed in

Answer (score 1):

http://geekswithblogs.net/seanfao/archive/2009/12/03/136680.aspx

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/Managing-Entity-Framework-ObjectContext-lifespan-and-scope-in-n-layered-ASP-NET-applications.aspx

download the code (from dotnetslackers), it use entity framework 3.5, but at least you will have a fair idea how to start.